# Map Return Null or empty Android Studio

Tags: java, android, null, gps, return

I am new to programming in android and need to make a GPS app, I created a small app with graphic interface for test but I don't achievement do working the map, this returned null and I couldn't solve this. I leave my code when I think that break. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    Double latInicial,longInicial,latFinal,longFinal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

        //    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        /////////////
        LatLng center = null;
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

       // setUpMapIfNeeded();

        // recorriendo todas las rutas
        for(int i=0;i<Utilidades.routes.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Obteniendo el detalle de la ruta
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = Utilidades.routes.get(i);

            // Obteniendo todos los puntos y/o coordenadas de la ruta
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                if (center == null) {
                    //Obtengo la 1ra coordenada para centrar el mapa en la misma.
                    center = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                }
                points.add(position);
            }

            // Agregamos todos los puntos en la ruta al objeto LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            //Definimos el grosor de las Polilíneas
            lineOptions.width(2);
            //Definimos el color de la Polilíneas
            lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        // Dibujamos las Polilineas en el Google Map para cada ruta
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);

        LatLng origen = new LatLng(Utilidades.coordenadas.getLatitudInicial(), Utilidades.coordenadas.getLongitudInicial());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origen).title("Lat: "+Utilidades.coordenadas.getLatitudInicial()+" - Long: "+Utilidades.coordenadas.getLongitudInicial()));

        LatLng destino = new LatLng(Utilidades.coordenadas.getLatitudFinal(), Utilidades.coordenadas.getLongitudFinal());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destino).title("Lat: "+Utilidades.coordenadas.getLatitudFinal()+" - Long: "+Utilidades.coordenadas.getLongitudFinal()));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 15));
        /////////////
    }
```

### }

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas.MapsActivity" />
```

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzeuy.png This is error  ]

```
package co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtLatInicio,txtLongInicio,txtLatFinal,txtLongFinal;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    RequestQueue request;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        txtLatInicio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLatIni);
        txtLongInicio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLongIni);
        txtLatFinal= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLatFin);
        txtLongFinal= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLongFin);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Utilidades.coordenadas.setLatitudInicial(Double.valueOf(txtLatInicio.getText().toString()));
                Utilidades.coordenadas.setLongitudInicial(Double.valueOf(txtLongInicio.getText().toString()));
                Utilidades.coordenadas.setLatitudFinal(Double.valueOf(txtLatFinal.getText().toString()));
                Utilidades.coordenadas.setLongitudFinal(Double.valueOf(txtLongFinal.getText().toString()));

                webServiceObtenerRuta(txtLatInicio.getText().toString(),txtLongInicio.getText().toString(),
                        txtLatFinal.getText().toString(),txtLongFinal.getText().toString());

                Intent miIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(miIntent);
            }
        });

        request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void webServiceObtenerRuta(String latitudInicial, String longitudInicial, String latitudFinal, String longitudFinal) {

        String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+latitudInicial+","+longitudInicial
                +"&destination="+latitudFinal+","+longitudFinal;

        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //Este método PARSEA el JSONObject que retorna del API de Rutas de Google devolviendo
                //una lista del lista de HashMap Strings con el listado de Coordenadas de Lat y Long,
                //con la cual se podrá dibujar pollinas que describan la ruta entre 2 puntos.
                JSONArray jRoutes = null;
                JSONArray jLegs = null;
                JSONArray jSteps = null;

                try {

                    jRoutes = response.getJSONArray("routes");

                    /** Traversing all routes */
                    for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                        jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                        /** Traversing all legs */
                        for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                            jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                            /** Traversing all steps */
                            for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                                String polyline = "";
                                polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                                List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                                /** Traversing all points */
                                for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                                    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                                    hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                                    path.add(hm);
                                }
                            }
                            Utilidades.routes.add(path);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se puede conectar "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println();
                Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
            }
        }
        );

        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){
        //Este método PARSEA el JSONObject que retorna del API de Rutas de Google devolviendo
        //una lista del lista de HashMap Strings con el listado de Coordenadas de Lat y Long,
        //con la cual se podrá dibujar pollinas que describan la ruta entre 2 puntos.
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    Utilidades.routes.add(path);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        return Utilidades.routes;
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId()==R.id.btnObtenerCoordenadas){
           // txtLatInicio.setText("4.543986"); txtLongInicio.setText("-75.666736");
            txtLatInicio.setText("-34.616516"); txtLongInicio.setText("-58.555252");
            //Unicentro
            //txtLatFinal.setText("4.540026"); txtLongFinal.setText("-75.665479");
            txtLatFinal.setText("-34.604833"); txtLongFinal.setText("-58.564333");
            //Parque del café
            //  txtLatFinal.setText("4.541396"); txtLongFinal.setText("-75.771741");
        }

    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}


package co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas;

/**
 * Created by CHENAO on 29/07/2018.
 */

public class Punto {

    private Double latitudInicial;
    private Double longitudInicial;
    private Double latitudFinal;
    private Double longitudFinal;

    public Double getLatitudInicial() {
        return latitudInicial;
    }

    public void setLatitudInicial(Double latitudInicial) {
        this.latitudInicial = latitudInicial;
    }

    public Double getLongitudInicial() {
        return longitudInicial;
    }

    public void setLongitudInicial(Double longitudInicial) {
        this.longitudInicial = longitudInicial;
    }

    public Double getLatitudFinal() {
        return latitudFinal;
    }

    public void setLatitudFinal(Double latitudFinal) {
        this.latitudFinal = latitudFinal;
    }

    public Double getLongitudFinal() {
        return longitudFinal;
    }

    public void setLongitudFinal(Double longitudFinal) {
        this.longitudFinal = longitudFinal;
    }
}

package co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by CHENAO on 25/08/2018.
 */

public class Utilidades {
    public static List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    public static Punto coordenadas=new Punto();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Did you get  google map api key? If not then Follow this. get the  google map api key and paste into "res/values/google_maps_api.xml"-->
<resources>
<!-- TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.
See this page for more information:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key
Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
Note: This resource is used for the debug build target. Update this file if you just want to run
the demo app.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
    YOUR_KEY_HERE
</string>
```

Comment: hello I already have the key but still does not work, the application stops when you want to open the map

Comment: At this moment I can not, but the terminal does not show any errors, but when I debug it appears that the maps are null. Later I send that error

Comment: Please check these google samples: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java

Comment: ok thanks, is there any specific part that you recommend to see? I download the code and saw that it doesn't compile

Comment: sorry. I just want you to see the code how they are giving the latitude.

Answer (score 0):

Start by placing `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml.

What are your play services dependencies in build.gradle (in app level)?

check for:

```
//play services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi  @moises, I used this                                                                                 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
// implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.6'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'´

Comment: Put <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your AndroidManifest.xml and check logcat messages while your app starts. Google Maps SDK needs internet access. Do this now and tell me what appears in your logcat.

Comment: hello @moises  I tried what you suggested and I pass the following when I add the services implementation services-maps: 16.1.0 the application remains the same, I touch the search button and it stops without opening the map, when I remove it and add location: 16.0. 0, I get that another location service already exists. Also try to update the google play services from 12 to 16 and the application does not open directly try to open and stop

Comment: Note that the declaration of the map fragment needs a correction in "android: name ="        



        `<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas.MapsActivity"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="br.com.nextter.ui.activity.MainActivity" />`



You have not been informed if you have already added the internet permission.

Comment: Also add the *class* property in the declaration of your fragment as above.

`class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: The internet permission already added but It still equal , later I will test the new suggests

Comment: hello @moises I corrected the name of the fragment and added the property of the class that you mentioned and I am still stopping the map when I click on the button that looks up the map, and the internet permissions are already added. In the cat lot I throw the following: 6519-6519/co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas, PID: 6519
  java.lang.NullPointerException: PolylineOptions cannot be null                    I used the play service map is 10.2.6

Comment: Hi @EzequielLedesma, great! the map rendering problem is solved. `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: co.quindio.sena.ejemplomaparutas` it's already another problem. 
Disable all code in onMapReady and run the app, let's see if the map loads without problems. What exactly do you want to do with these Polylines?

Try somethink like:

 `Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED))` to test.

Comment: I want to send the coordinates by a button and I can graph the route with the start and end point, I have three more classes that I did not upload, now I upload it so that it is understood

Comment: I tried to add what you said to try and as it says google and it throws me that can not be solved @moises